# Genymotion emulator is not turning on

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

Genymotion emulator is not turning on for more than 5 min it showing **"Optimizing app 73 of 74"** Check the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: How many times have you tried?

Comment: What is your genymotion and android version?

Comment: Android Studio 1.2 and Genymotion 2.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer the problem is with low ram management in my computer I have 2gb ram so genymotion required more ram if you are opening with  android studio. **so what I did I open the new version first then run the android studio**